# Why text with linebreaks doesn't appear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I've a div with text and a button. When I press the button nice textarea containing the text from the div has got to appear. But if there's linebreaks in the text textarea doesn't appear at all. Why can it be?

```
<a id="r" href='javascript:void(0);' onclick="
        var text = '$row[text]';
        document.getElementById('edit').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('editsubmit').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('editarea').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('editarea').value=text;
        document.getElementById('editarea').focus();
        "
        >Edit</a>
```

Text is from database. Before to put it there it's processed like that:

```
$text = preg_replace("/[\r\n]{5,}/i", "\r\n\r\n\r\n", $text);
```

Comment: what you have tried? Please show your code also

Comment: Try `.next('textarea')`

Comment: You should show some code how you convert `div` to `textarea` and back. The problem is probably: linebreak in `div` is `<br>`, linebreak in `textarea` have to be `\n`

Answer (score 1):

Inside textareas you can use `\n` instead of `<br>` to achieve line breaking.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all your line breaks in plain text with appropriate HTML, basically a single newline becomes an HTML line break `<br />` and a new line followed by a blank line becomes a paragraph break `</p>`.